# How can I SELECT from multiple tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter, select, join

I have three tables: (to keep it simple I'll only show the relevant fields)

```
Articles (id, title, text, author)
Comments (id, article_id, text, author)
Users (user_id, user_type, first_name, last_name, email, password)
```

In the `articles` table, because an author can have multiple articles, I only store the author's `user_id` from the `users` table, and I do the same for the `comments` table.

My problem is when I run an ActiveRecord query in the articles_model to get all articles along with that articles associated comments, and then echo the author in my view with `$row->author`, I only get the author's user_id which is 1, 2, 3, etc etc.

How do I go into the `users` table (different table) in that same query and get the authors actual `first_name` and `last_name` and return that?

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
$data['articles'] = $this->getArticles();
$this->load->view('articles_view', $data);

function getArticles() {
  $this->load->model('articles_model');
  $articles = $this->articles_model->getAllArticles();
  return $articles;
}
```

articles_model:

```
function getAllArticles() {
  $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
  $query = $this->db->get('articles');
  return $query;
}
```

articles_view:

```
<?php foreach($articles->result() as $row) { ?>
<?php echo $row->author ?>
<?php echo $row->text ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I have a ton of other fields, but this is an extremely stripped down version for simplicity's sake.

If I echo the above `$row->author`, I'm only going to get the user_id.  I need to get the user's name from the `users` table instead.  Surely I don't have to do another separate function call and pass more information into the view.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated and would actually open up a world for me :)

Comment: I cant speak for CI's specifically but normally there are `join` methods on your db class... or sometimes specific join methods on the models like `getWith` or `findWith`.

Comment: Is the 'author' in articles and comments table is foreign key from users table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (or just have an idea):

I assumed that `user_id` from your `users` table is foreign key of `articles` and `comments` table since you said that the authors and commentators `user_id` are stored in `users` table.

**On your controller:**

```
$data['articles'] = $this->getArticles(); 
$this->load->view('articles_view', $data);

function getArticles() { 
   $this->load->model('articles_model'); 
   $articles = $this->articles_model->getArticlesById(); 
   return $articles; 
}
```

**On your model:**

```
// this will get the article of a certain author   
function getArticlesById()
{
   $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3)); 
   $q = $this->db->get('articles'); 
   if($q->num_rows() > 0)
   {
       $q = $q->row_array();
       $result = $this->getCommentsAndAuthors($row);
       return $result;
   }
   return 0;
}

// this will get the comments of each articles of the author and the author of the comments
function getCommentsAndAuthors($row)
{
    $result = $data = array();

    $this->db->select('c.*, u.firstname, u.lastname');
    $this->db->from('users u');
    $this->db->where('u.id', $row['user_id']);
    $this->db->join('comments c', 'c.id = u.id');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    foreach($q->result_array() as $col)
    {
        $data[] = $col;
    }
    $result['article'] = $row;
    $result['comments'] = $data;
    return $result;
}
```

I'm not sure if its work but that's the idea.

Comment: Actually I'm working with the MyISAM storage engine which doesn't support foreign keys.  Any suggestions?  I could convert all my tables to InnoDB but that is going to be a lot of tedious work that I hope to avoid.

Comment: @JoeyDuke: what do you mean doesn't support foreign key's?? Your `user_id` column in the `articles` table is a foreign key. Any database support foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works well for me which I will post and try to explain.

My Controller is like this:

```
function fullArticle()
{
    $data['article'] = $this->getArticleDetail();
   $data['comments'] = $this->getNewsTrendsComments();
   $this->load->view('inner_view', $data);
}

function getArticleDetail()
{
   $this->load->model('articles_model');
   $articles = $this->articles_model->getArticles();
   return $articles;
}

function getComments()
{
   $this->load->model('articles_model');
   $comments = $this->articles_model->getComments();
   return $comments;
}


articles_model:
function getArticles()
{
   $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
   $query = $this->db->get('articles');
   return $query;
}

function getComments()
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('comments w');
   $this->db->where('article_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
   $this->db->join('users wc','w.author = wc.user_id');
   $data = $this->db->get();
   return $data;
}
```

As you can see, the getComments function in my model was the key.  It's the JOIN statement that handles what I was trying to accomplish.  I know there are probably cleaner and more efficient ways to do this, by combining the two functions, but as a beginner I wanted to keep it easier to understand.

Hopefully this can help others.